# How to render purescript-halogen components into the <head> tag

Tags: purescript, halogen

How can I render a specific purescript-halogen component into the <head> tag?

The following example written for Halogen 1.0.0 renders the stylesheet and the paragraph into the HTML body:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff      (Eff)
import Data.Maybe             (Maybe(Nothing))

import CSS                    as C
import Halogen                as H
import Halogen.Aff            as HA
import Halogen.HTML           as HH
import Halogen.HTML.CSS       as HS
import Halogen.Query.HalogenM as HQ
import Halogen.VDom.Driver    as HV

styles :: forall p i. HH.HTML p i
styles = HS.stylesheet $
    C.select C.body $ C.margin C.nil C.nil C.nil C.nil

content :: forall p i. HH.HTML p i
content = HH.p_ [ HH.text "Test" ]

main :: Eff (HA.HalogenEffects ()) Unit
main = HA.runHalogenAff $ HA.awaitBody >>= HV.runUI ui unit
  where
    ui = H.component { initialState : const unit
                     , render       : const render
                     , eval         : const $ HQ.halt "no query"
                     , receiver     : const Nothing
                     }

    render = HH.div_ [ styles, content ]
```

The DOM is generated as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script async="" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <style type="text/css">
                body { margin: 0 0 0 0 }
            </style>
            <p>
                Test
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This example works but according to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) the style element is only allowed "where metadata content is expected", i.e. the <head> element. So I want to render the stylesheet there. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why render the stylesheet with Halogen if it is completely static? It is possible to render style attributes on specific elements if one needs that flexibility. But the question in general is still interesting... I'm thinking about <title>.

Comment: Rendering a static stylesheet in Purescript has the following advantages: You can use the full power of PureScript to assemble the stylesheet and do not need another CSS preprocessor like Sass or Less. Furthermore you can modularize the code so that the Halogen components are stored together with their styles. Using style attributes is not an option if you need media queries or pseudo-classes like `:hover`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the `awaitBody` function - as well as waiting for it to load, this selects the `body` element, which is not really what you want in this case. If you want to write to the `head` then you're going to need to select that and pass it to `runUI` for a component that renders a stylesheet.

You'll also need to run two separate components, one for the `head`, one for the `body`:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Aff.Console (CONSOLE)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)

import Data.Const (Const)
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Data.Newtype (unwrap)

import Halogen as H
import Halogen.Aff as HA
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Halogen.VDom.Driver (runUI)

bodyComponent :: forall m. H.Component HH.HTML (Const Void) Unit Void m
bodyComponent =
  H.component
    { initialState: const unit
    , render: const $ HH.div_ [ HH.text "A component" ]
    , eval: absurd <<< unwrap
    , receiver: const Nothing
    }

styleComponent :: forall m. H.Component HH.HTML (Const Void) Unit Void m
styleComponent =
  H.component
    { initialState: const unit
    , render: const $ HH.style_ [ HH.text "body { background: #222; color: #eee }"]
    , eval: absurd <<< unwrap
    , receiver: const Nothing
    }

main :: Eff (HA.HalogenEffects (console :: CONSOLE)) Unit
main = HA.runHalogenAff do
  HA.awaitLoad
  traverse_ (runUI styleComponent unit) =<< HA.selectElement "head"
  traverse_ (runUI bodyComponent unit) =<< HA.selectElement "body"
```

If they need to communicate then you could use the `subscribe` and `driver` functions from the `HalogenIO` record that `runUI` produces to set up channels between them.

I had concerns about doing this, as you're supposed to pass through an element that is empty as the target for where a container will render... but when using the Halogen-provided `VDom` driver it appears to behave at least, in that the `<head>` contents won't be replaced by the style component (it is appended to the end). This is basically unspecified behaviour though, so I'm not sure it would necessarily hold true with other drivers.

Comment: I tried your proposal but I could not run two components with `runUI`. Only the first one gets rendered. Then I tried to run two Halogen instances with `runHalogenAff` and that worked. I have no use for the two components/instances to communicate with each other so this is OK for me. The instances add their element to the `head` respectively the `body` element and do not replace their contents so there is no problem with rewriting as you guessed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a very trivial working example. I'm not sure what problems you might have been having, but using `runUI` twice seems to work fine for me!

Comment: The mistake in my code was that `awaitLoad` was actually called twice. Your example works fine. Thanks!